# ASP.NET MVC OnAuthorization отличие от AuthorizeCore

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Добрый день. Помогите разобраться в чем разница между `OnAuthorization` и `AuthorizeCore` ? При гуглении в основном ответ что возвращаемым типом. Но при этом видел версию, что `OnAuthorization` - это первый запускаемый метод при запросе прав. При этом не понятно тогда, зачем нужен второй.

Используя этот код

```
public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
}
protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
    return true;
}
```

выходит , что пользователь не авторизован. Но если закоментить `OnAuthorization` тогда работает. Помогите разобраться в чем разница между этими методами. Спасибо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все очень просто. `OnAuthorization` вызывает внутри `AuthorizeCore`, если не переопределен.

Вот код `OnAuthorization`:

```
public virtual void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    if (filterContext == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
    }
    if (OutputCacheAttribute.IsChildActionCacheActive(filterContext))
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(MvcResources.AuthorizeAttribute_CannotUseWithinChildActionCache);
    }
    bool flag = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute), true) || filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute), true);
    if (flag)
    {
        return;
    }
    if (this.AuthorizeCore(filterContext.HttpContext))
    {
        HttpCachePolicyBase cache = filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache;
        cache.SetProxyMaxAge(new TimeSpan(0L));
        cache.AddValidationCallback(new HttpCacheValidateHandler(this.CacheValidateHandler), null);
        return;
    }
    this.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
}
```

Как видно, метод `OnAuthorization` в реализации по умолчанию делает некоторую дополнительную работу:

- делает быструю проверку на разрешение анонимного доступа, и ничего не делает если анонимный доступ разрешен;
- запрещает кэширование результатов на стороне прокси-сервера (что логично);
- настраивает выходной кэш так, чтобы проверять доступ каждый раз перед выдачей кешированной страницы.

Если вы переопределите `OnAuthorization` и не вызовите базовую реализацию - эти три безусловно полезных шага не будут сделаны. Если же вы вызовите базовую реализацию - то и `AuthorizeCore` также будет вызван. Отсюда вывод: всегда переопределяйте `AuthorizeCore`, и никогда `OnAuthorization` - если только вам не захочется сделать что-нибудь особенно хитрое.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. При наследовании от AutorizeAttribute, и override OnAuthorization, таким образом чтобы этот метод был с пустым телом { }, результат авторизации определяется тогда только методом AuthorizeCore() если его тоже переопределить по-своему ?  Подскажите пожалуйста, где вы берете информацию об исходном коде ?

Comment: Вы как читаете? Если переопределить `OnAuthorization` с пустым телом, то `AuthorizeCore` вообще не будет вызван.

Comment: А с исходным кодом все просто - ILSpy.

Comment: Читал внимательно, просто в своем коде не правильно составил пример и запутался. Вы правы. Спасибо большое за помощь.